# basic javascript image gallery logic error?

Tags: javascript

i've attempted to make a very simple image gallery, which is functional for the most except for the back function. the next function loops around perfectly, but the back function includes a blank image (where it cant locate one), i think  theres something wrong with my  logic but im not sure where, if someone could point it out id be very grateful.
the error message is :GET file:///G:/eject/undefined net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

```
 var myImage= new Array(); 
myImage[1]="images/product/linkin.jpg";       
myImage[2]="images/product/lisagerrard.jpg";
myImage[3]="images/product/maddy.jpg";
myImage[4]="images/product/mariah.jpg";

var image = 1;
function next()
{ 
    image++;
    document.getElementById("picture3").style.background = 'url(' + myImage[image] + ')';
    if (image==4)
    {
    image = 0;
    }
  }

function  back()
{
 image--;
    document.getElementById("picture3").style.background = 'url(' + myImage[image] + ')';
    if (image== 0)
    {
    image = 5;
    }
}
```

html :

```
  <a id ="f1" onclick="back();return false;" href="#"> back </a> <a id ="f2" onclick="next();return false;" href="#"> next </a>
```

Comment: Mind me asking why you're using 1 based indexes in a 0 based language?

Comment: well, i noticed it was excluding the first image when i started it at 0... so i tried 1...  i guess thats why :x .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the back function, you decrement the counter, then try to display the image before you do the out of bounds check. To resolve, move the out of bounds check to before you try to display the image:

```
function  back()
{
    image--;
    if (image== 0)
    {
        image = 4; // also go to 4 not 5
    }
    document.getElementById("picture3").style.background = 'url(' + myImage[image] + ')';
}
```

Comment: :D thank you, especially the explanation. i really appreciate the help.